A tag for empirical measures and or tests
We currently have test assessment and measurement all used to refer to what I most commonly hear referred to as tests or measures.
IMO there's some value in keeping them separate, but it needs to be consistent. IQ is a measure, an IQ test is a test of that measure. A test is a reusable, explicit thing you can hand out to participants. A measure is more abstract and is usually the scale on which tests are scored. Tests are the means to compare scores along a measure.
I can see them being separate to separate issues like biased tests and methodology of administering tests vs comparing the validity of the measures themselves.
I'm not entirely apposed to having them as one tag as they're very related, so I'd like to hear what the general opinion is.

measurement is more general than 'tests and measures', for instance in this question.

At the time of writing there are:

17 questions tagged test: Questions pertaining to the evaluation of performance through formal or informal means, as well as the scoring of such evaluations.
37 questions tagged measurement: For questions about techniques for measuring psychological and neural properties. Includes the measurement of knowledge, abilities, attitudes, and personality traits, as well as neural structure, organization, activity, and complexity.
7 questions tagged assessment: For questions about measuring performance via standard or custom tests.

First of all I see no use in keeping assessment around, and would make it a synonym of measurement. 3 questions had both tags applied to them. I checked all 7 questions, and don't see any reason to differentiate between them.
The second discussion is whether or not we should merge test and measurement. Assuming assessment is a synonym of measurement, 9 out of 17 test questions have both tags applied to them.
If we are to differentiate between them, we should update their descriptions to reflect the difference more clearly. As Ben Brocka suggested, a test would be a measurement instrument, while a measurement reflects a certain psychological or neural property.
Looking through all the questions tagged test, I feel it's not worthwhile making this distinction. Unless someone can make a strong case why there is a real need to differentiate between the two of them, I feel it would be appropriate to simply make test a synonym of measurement.
P.s.: psychometricsis already a synonym of measurement.

In case the community does feel it's worthwhile having [tag:test] around, I suggest perhaps creating the tag [tag:measurement-instrument], and making [tag:test] a synonym of that? Additionally we would have to go through all existing [tag:test] questions in order to see whether they were tagged correctly. We also would have to determine when tagging with both [tag:measurement] and [tag:test] would be appropriate.

I would definitely make assessment a synonym of measurement. I also approve of making test a synonym of measurement, but I feel less strongly on that point.

I went ahead and already destroyed [tag:assessment] since everyone I talked to seemed to agree on that. I'm waiting on further input on what to do with [tag:test].

I personally agree that we should make [tag:test] a synonym of [tag:measurement]
